# Trying to removing last child of a child element

Tags: javascript

Trying to remove the last child of the "leftSideImages" so that the right side has one less the the images on the left. Below is my code. The goal is to clone the images on the left onto the right minus one. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <style>
        div {
            position: absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px
        }
        img { 
            position: absolute
        }
        #rightSide { 
            left: 500px; 
            border-left: 1px solid black 
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function generateFaces(){

            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

            for ( var i = 0; i< numberOfFaces; i++){
                var random_top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
                var random_left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src="smile.png";
                img.style.top = random_top + "px";
                img.style.left = random_left + "px";


                theLeftSide.appendChild(img);

            }
            var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
            //this doesn't work         leftSideImages.removeChild(theLeftSide.lastChild);
            // it gets rid of everything.
            // I'm trying to clone the left side onto the right with one less image
            theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Matching Game</h3>
      <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
      <div id="leftSide"></div>
      <div id="rightSide"></div>
      <script>generateFaces()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `theLeftSide.lastChild` isn't a child of `leftSideImages`, it's a child of `theLeftSide`.

Comment: When you cloned `theLeftSide`, you also cloned all its children because you said `deep = true`.

Comment: Just to clarify. I want to keep the left side intact. I only want to remove one of the images on the right side. The last one. Thank you.

Comment: That is very clear in the question.

Comment: On the left side, the images are children of the `leftSide` DIV. But on the right side, you're cloning the `leftSide` DIV, removing the last child from that, and then appending that whole DIV as a child of `rightSide`. So the images will be grandchildren of `rightSide`. Is that what you really wanted?

Comment: Why don't you just clone each image except for the last one, and append the clones to `theRightSide` individually? Then the structure of both sides will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *removeChild* and *lastElementChild*, like this :

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("leftSide");
parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild);
```

```html
<div id="leftSide">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hors that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the child of a different element than the one you're calling `removeChild` on. It should be:

```
leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
```

I'm not sure why your code removed everything. According to the documentation, it should throw an exception if the argument is not a child of the given parent.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are cloning whole left side and then removing last child which is the whole left side,

```
  var leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
  //leftSideImages now has whole theLeftSide - the div not its content.

  var i,l, children;
  children = theLeftSide.childNodes;
  i=0;
  l = children.length;

  for( i; i< l ; i++){
    theRightSide.appendChild(children[i].cloneNode(true));
  }

  theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.lastChild);
```

Keep in mind there might be better solutions.

Here is fiddle to show you that it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0hrre90/

Comment: Put the solution in the answer, not just in the fiddle.

Comment: Sure thing. done - The fiddle just demonstrate better is all.

Answer (score 0):

Use leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild); 
instead of leftSideImages.removeChild(theLeftSide.lastChild);

It's correct one which already given one of the friend. :-)
Also I have run same thing at my machine.